# Is there a way to handle immutability that's robust and scalable?

Tags: google-bigquery

Since bigquery is append-only, I was thinking about stamping each record I upload to it with an 'effective date' similar to how peoplesoft works, if anybody is familiar with that pattern.

Then, I could issue a select statement and join on the max effective date

```
select UTC_USEC_TO_MONTH(timestamp) as month, sum(amt)/100 as sales
from foo.orders as all
join (select id, max(effdt) as max_effdt from foo.orders group by id) as latest
on all.effdt = latest.max_effdt and all.id = latest.id
group by month
order by month;
```

Unfortunately, I believe this won't scale because of the big query 'small joins' restriction, so I wanted to see if anyone else had thought around this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, adding a timestamp for each record (or in some cases, a flag that captures the state of a particular record) is the right approach. The small side of a BigQuery "Small Join" can actually return *at least* 8MB (this value is compressed on our end, so is usually 2 to 10 times larger), so for "lookup" table type subqueries, this can actually provide a lot of records.

In your case, it's not clear to me what the exact query you are trying to run is.. it looks like you are trying to return the most recent sales times of every individual item - and then JOIN this information with the SUM of sales amt per month of each item? Can you provide more info about the query?

It might be possible to do this all in one query. For example, in our wikipedia dataset, an example might look something like...

```
SELECT contributor_username,  UTC_USEC_TO_MONTH(timestamp * 1000000) as month, 
SUM(num_characters) as total_characters_used FROM 
[publicdata:samples.wikipedia] WHERE (contributor_username != '' or 
contributor_username IS NOT NULL) AND timestamp > 1133395200 
AND timestamp < 1157068800 GROUP BY contributor_username, month 
ORDER BY contributor_username DESC, month DESC;
```

...to provide wikipedia contributions per user per month (like sales per month per item). This result is actually really large, so you would have to limit by date range.

**UPDATE** (based on comments below) a similar query that finds  "num_characters" for the latest wikipedia revisions by contributors after a particular time...

```
SELECT current.contributor_username, current.num_characters
FROM
(SELECT contributor_username, num_characters, timestamp as time FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] WHERE contributor_username != '' AND contributor_username IS NOT NULL)
AS current
JOIN
(SELECT contributor_username, MAX(timestamp) as time FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] WHERE contributor_username != '' AND contributor_username  IS NOT NULL AND timestamp > 1265073722 GROUP BY contributor_username) AS latest
ON 
current.contributor_username = latest.contributor_username
AND
current.time = latest.time;
```

If your query requires you to use first build a large aggregate (for example, you need to run essentially an accurate COUNT DISTINCT) another option is to break this query up into two queries. The first query could provide the max effective date by month along with a count and save this result as a new table. Then, could run a sum query on the resulting table.

You could also store monthly sales records in separate tables, and only query the particular table for the months you are interested in, simplifying your monthly sales summaries (this could also be a more economical use of BigQuery). When you need to find aggregates across all tables, you could run your queries with multiple tables listed after the FROM clause.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What i'm tying to do is a little bit different. I want to to append modifications to tables by timestamping the latest valid values. For example, I have a table of orders that I export to big query, but those orders might change over time, so instead of rebuilding the whole bigquery table, I just want to append the differences. An order might have ID 1, timestamp 1, amt 100. If the amt decreases 50, I want to update it by sending record with ID 1, timestamp 2, amt -50, which would make the total sum of the records $50. Make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I would update it by sending ID 1, timestamp 2, amt 50. It would disregard the previous value and only use the latest one because of the grouping on effdt and joining on id

Comment: @user395265: just to be clear, does appending only the latest values to your BigQuery table solve your problem? You could use your timestamp to filter the transaction data by date range, find the maximum  time in that batch, then JOIN this to find the latest value (see update above). Also, would it make more sense to create a new table that captures a snapshot of the daily values?